# How can I update my staging with with the users from the live site?

Tags: users, staging

I have a staging site I am about to push live, however I have a bunch of users on the live site that I need to pull over to the staging site before I push it up to the live site. I have google searched everything I can and haven't been able to find an actual answer to the question of whether there is a way to do that or not.

Do any of y'all know how I can pull only my users from my live site and import them into my staging site?

Thanks

Comment: Code always moves upstream. Databases always move downstream. You can try to migrate the users.

Comment: Copy the database down.

Comment: Unfortunately there are a lot of database changes on the staging database so I can't just copy the whole database down

Comment: I also recommend a migration of users. It is a supported process.

Comment: @cilefen I haven't been able to find much documentation on how to migrate user from one drupal 8 site to another. Do you know where I could find documentation on how to do that?

Comment: Drupal 8 is end-of-life.

Comment: Yes thank you I am aware of that. That is also on my plate of things to do. However before I get to the Drupal 8 -> Drupal 9 bit I have to get past the migrate prod users to staging site bit. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: Yes, migrate them. Migration is a big topic. Some people use a CSV to import users. And there are factors like is there a requirement to preserve IDs and links to authorship, etc. Requests for documentation are against the rules of this forum (although documentation links are often given). See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/tour. This forum is set up to answer direct questions.